# How to create a bootable partition with an ntfs file system that is compatible with a Windows 8.1 boot USB drive

Tags: linux, command-line, partition, windows, kali-linux

I've been trying to use `fdisk` and `gparted` and I believe that I have a suitable partition on `/dev/sdb1`.

Here is my command list:

```
fdisk /dev/sdb1

  n        (I filled the whole drive with a new partition)
  t 86     (I set the type to "NTFS volume set", there are 2 with the exact same name and I chose the first)
  a        (I toggled the bootable flag to on)
  w        (to save changes)

umount /dev/sdb1
mkntfs /dev/sdb1
```

After all of that, I restarted and booted from my Windows disc drive. However, it retrieved a list of bootable drives that did not include `/dev/sdb1`.

Where am I going wrong? Specifically, how can I alter `/dev/sdb1` so that it is visible to the Windows 8.1 installation software?

---

More information:

When I boot from the Windows 8.1 installation disc, I notice that the drive `/dev/sda1` is listed as type "System".

`/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sda3` are listed as type "Primary".

The installation software allows a link to "Format" the System partition. This is greyed out on the other two.

(I don't want to format my System partition because if, for some reason the software fails, I will have no OS and no computer with an OS and, to me, that's not a smart risk to take.)

When creating a new partition, fdisk only offers the options "Primary" and "Extended". Just a hunch, but I don't think extended is what I need.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking how to install Windows.

Comment: all i can tell from your wall of text is that you've installed kali and now want to install windows as well.  try editing your question to make it on-topic for this site.  hint: whitespace and paragraph breaks are free.

Comment: @JeffSchaller it seems to be asking how to prepare a disk for installation of Windows. The preparation is using Unix/Linux commands so I don't see that this task is any more or less off topic than any other.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be that you've applied fdisk to the *partition* `/dev/sdb1` instead of the *disk* `/dev/sdb`. The result of this is that the partition `/dev/sdb1` now has a disk layout inside it that contains (if you like) `/dev/sdb1p1` as the NTFS drive.

To take over the entire of your `/dev/sdb` disk the `fdisk` command should be applied to the disk device `/dev/sdb` instead.

However, I don't think that any of this will really help Windows 8.x install itself. It uses at least two if not three partitions so you would probably be better off just erasing the disk partition label and letting it use the entire disk as it sees fit. This command will erase the partition table for the entire disk:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=10 of=/dev/sdb    # Flattens the ENTIRE DISK
```